# Python pandas has no attribute ols - Error (rolling OLS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

For my evaluation, I wanted to run a rolling 1000 window `OLS regression estimation` of the dataset found in this URL:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUa3dPYW5tejA0bzg
using the following `Python` script.

```
# /usr/bin/python -tt

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

df = pd.read_csv('estimated.csv', names=('x','y'))

model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.Y, x=df[['y']], 
                               window_type='rolling', window=1000, intercept=True)
df['Y_hat'] = model.y_predict
```

However, when I run my Python script, I am getting this error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas.stats' has no attribute 'ols'`. Could this error be from the version that I am using? The `pandas` installed on my Linux node has a version of `0.20.2`

Comment: What happens with `from pandas.stats import ols`?

Comment: It says `ImportError: cannot import name 'ols'`.

Comment: What do you get with `print (dir(pd.stats))`? I'm not at laptop atm, will be back home soon to test myself. Is it in the list?

Comment: This is what i get. `['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'api', 'moments']`. It seems the `ols` is not listed.

Comment: What did you call your script?

Comment: I call it `reg_test.py`.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on version 0.17 and it's there in `dir`. I guess they restructured.

Comment: Very strange. Let me see if there is a way to install it with the latest version of `pandas` - otherwise I will rollback my current version to 0.17 which i think is not a good idea though.

Comment: It possibly comes with another module now. I'm looking into it too, don't roll back, it's just a shame that the docs don't make it explicit where it's imported from now

Comment: what about `from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS` taken from http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/importpaths.html#import-examples

Comment: @downshift you might be on the right lines here. It looks like it was deprecated in pandas https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ols&type=

Comment: right, i think since v0.20.0 - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b0d9ee0b4c0911e089d4dd7c6a676557909fb7da/doc/source/whatsnew/v0.20.0.txt#L1525

Comment: @downshift then you have the answer :) Quite a substantial change there!

Answer (score 8):

`pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS` was removed in Pandas version 0.20.0

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-prior-deprecations

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11898

I can't find an 'off the shelf' solution for what should be such an obvious use case as rolling regressions.

The following should do the trick without investing too much time in a more elegant solution.  It uses numpy to calculate the predicted value of the regression based on the regression parameters and the X values in the rolling window.

```
window = 1000
a = np.array([np.nan] * len(df))
b = [np.nan] * len(df)  # If betas required.
y_ = df.y.values
x_ = df[['x']].assign(constant=1).values
for n in range(window, len(df)):
    y = y_[(n - window):n]
    X = x_[(n - window):n]
    # betas = Inverse(X'.X).X'.y
    betas = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
    y_hat = betas.dot(x_[n, :])
    a[n] = y_hat
    b[n] = betas.tolist()  # If betas required.
```

The code above is equivalent to the following and about 35% faster:

```
model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.y, x=df.x, window_type='rolling', window=1000, intercept=True)
y_pandas = model.y_predict
```

Comment: Yes, that's right as I have learned from the comments above. So, do you have any idea on how we can use it with the latest version of `Pandas`?

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos What results do you want from the rolling regression (e.g. slope, intercept, predicted value, etc)

Comment: @Alexander, for example predicted value. Thanks!

Comment: I actually rollback my `pandas` version to `0.18.0` and the `ols` is working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos  does the old package have any statistical feature which allow you to calculate the significance of the coefficients?

Comment: @Lost1, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It was [deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11898) in favor of statsmodels.

See here [examples how to use statsmodels rolling regression](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/rolling_ls.html).