# Is Pandas pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS reliable?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to run a rolling ols regression and the few mentions I've found used pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS but there doesn't seem to be any official documentation of that function. Is it reliable/stable? Is it depreciated?
[Example of a mention of this function from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089693/rolling-regression-estimation-in-python-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

That module has indeed been deprecated. I can't find the release notes exactly, but there was a deprecation warning in March 2016 that read:

```
FutureWarning: The pandas.stats.ols module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. We refer to external packages like statsmodels, see some examples here: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/regression.html
```

Here is the [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) module they're referring to.

Comment: I've searched the documentation of that module and couldn't find any mention of rolling regressions