# Puzzles with rolling windows for statsmodels RollingOLS

Tags: python, statsmodels, rolling-computation

I am quite confused with rolling windows for `statsmodels RollingOLS` which is described in the [RollingOLS example page](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/rolling_ls.html).
It mentions that

> Estimated values are aligned so that models estimated using data points t, (t+1), ..., (t + windows) are stored in location (t + windows).

I have some questions:

**Q1:** Assume we are at row t, if I set `RollingOLS(endog, exog, window=60)`, it estimates the model using data from [t - 60, t] (i.e. (t - 60), (t - 59), ..., t) which has 61 observations, right? But this is an window of 61 days.

**Q2:** If we use `model.params` to extract the estimated coefficients, the coefficients at row t is the OLS results using data from [t - 60, t] (i.e. (t - 60), (t - 59), ..., t), am I right?

**Q3:** If my guess in Q2 is right, how do we solve the rolling problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089693/rolling-regression-estimation-in-python-dataframe)? That is

> I want to run a rolling 100-day window OLS regression estimation, which is:

> First for the 101st row, I run a regression of Y-X1,X2,X3 using the 1st to 100th rows, and estimate Y for the 101st row;

> Then for the 102nd row, I run a regression of Y-X1,X2,X3 using the 2nd to 101st rows, and estimate Y for the 102nd row;

> Then for the 103rd row, I run a regression of Y-X1,X2,X3 using the 2nd to 101st rows, and estimate Y for the 103rd row;

> Until the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small typo in the example.  When `window` is `n`, the first value computed uses observations `0,1,...,n-1` and appears in `res.params[n-1]`. This is how it should be so that the window size is actually enforces.  You can see this here

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import seaborn

import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS

factors = pdr.get_data_famafrench("F-F_Research_Data_Factors", start="1-1-1926")[0]
industries = pdr.get_data_famafrench("10_Industry_Portfolios", start="1-1-1926")[0]

endog = industries.HiTec - factors.RF.values
exog = sm.add_constant(factors["Mkt-RF"])
rols = RollingOLS(endog, exog, window=60)
rres = rols.fit()
params = rres.params.copy()
params.index = np.arange(1, params.shape[0] + 1)
params.iloc[57:62]
```

Note that the index here is 1, 2, ..., so that the first is in position 60, indicating that 60 observations where used to compute the first estimate.

```
       const    Mkt-RF
58       NaN       NaN
59       NaN       NaN
60  0.876155  1.399240
61  0.879936  1.406578
62  0.953169  1.408826
```

To get the estimate using data up to and including any point `t`, use `res.params[t]`.

#### `shift`

If you want to observations to be aligned "out-of-sample" so that the parameter estimates using observations up-to-and-including observation `t` are aligned to `t+1`, you can use `shift`

```
params.shift(1).iloc[57:62]
```

You see the parameter values that were at 60 are now at 61.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I found the example page has been modified. Now my problem is solved.